# How to make multiple variables in one list into one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
C= ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

how do i make it into a new variable like this .?

```
Cnew=['a','b','c']
```

is there a function or anything i can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preserve order and remove duplicates, here's one approach using [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

C= ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
new_C = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(C).keys())
```

Although it seems like this would also suffice for your use case:

```
new_C = sorted(set(c))
```

It's also worth noting, if you didn't already know, that, lookups (checking for membership) in a `list` object (the data structure from your desired output), are of time-complexity `O(n)`, while lookups for `set` objects are `O(1)`. It all depends on what you're trying to do with your output, of course...

Comment: the 2nd function is perfect dude thanks

Comment: is there any way i can do it without set function though? because my assignment really focus on algorithms

Comment: Think about what you need to do. Go through each element in your list, check whether you've "seen" that elements before, and keep track of which elements have already been "seen"...

Comment: im really stuck ! :( can you please make the function that i can access #for j in range(len(final)):
    #if final.count(final[j]) > 1:
        #if j!= len(final)-1:
            #if final[j]==final[j+1]:
                #veryfinal.append(final[j])
    #else:
        #veryfinal.append(final[j])

Answer (score 4):

I'd turn the list into a set:

```
C= ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
Cnew = set(C)
```

Set's work very much like lists, but they only allow one of each element, which is what you want.  However, if you really want a list, simply convert the set back to a list via the `list` function.

### Per the request of the OP

```
C= ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
cNew = []
for value in C:
    if value not in cNew:
        cNew.append(value)
print(cNew)
```

Comment: how do i access a set though? and it gives me Cnew
{'a', 'c', 'b'} i want it to be in order , eventhough i can call a sort function

Comment: Use `sorted` with `list`.  sorted(list(set(C))

Comment: is there any way i can do it without set function though? because my assignment really focus on algorithms

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set()`, so:

```
newset = set(c)
print(new_set)
```